# Google Query Language: Count multiple columns based on conditions for each column and grouped by date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I would like use the QUERY function / Google Query Language in Google Sheets to count multiple columns based on conditions for each of these columns and grouped by date.

This is how the database looks (it is a list of emails sent out with a timestamp and info about if they were opened and clicked on):

| date | opened | clicked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-14 4:30:06 | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2021-09-14 4:30:10 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 2021-09-15 4:30:10 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2021-09-15 4:30:11 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 2021-09-15 4:30:18 | FALSE | FALSE |

This is the outcome that I need (I basically want to know how many emails per day were opened and clicked on):

| date | count opened | count clicked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-14 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-09-15 | 1 | 1 |

I know that I can achieve this for one column using the following query:

```
select
toDate(A),
count(B) where B=TRUE
group by toDate(A)
```

but if I try to apply the query to two columns it does not work:

```
select
toDate(K),
count(B) where B=TRUE,
count(C) where C=TRUE
group by toDate(K)
```

Is there elegant way to achieve this using a single formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the data in the query input into the type you want - in this case just remove all `FALSE` values from the table

`=(query(ARRAYFORMULA({A:A,SUBSTITUTE(B:C,"FALSE","")}), "select toDate(Col1),count(Col2),count(Col3)  where Col1 is not null group by toDate(Col1)"))`

[image]